# How to connect back to back line plots using a dashed line?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two datasets covering two different time periods which are back to back. One dataset goes from 0 to 87 and other goes from 88 to 100. Please see below. How do I connect those datasets using a dashed or any distinct line?

My code is as follows:

```
plt.plot(np.exp(ARIMA.fit.predict(start=88,end=100,dynamic=True)), color = 'red')
plt.plot(np.exp(original_data), color = 'blue')
```

[image]

Comment: You grab the last point of the blue line, and the first point of the red line, and plot between them with the appropriate style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably be lazy and do it like this :

```
fit_array = np.exp(ARIMA.fit.predict(start=88,end=100,dynamic=True))
long_array = np.concatenate([np.exp(original_data), fit_array])

plt.plot(long_array, color = 'blue')
plt.plot(fit_array, color = 'red')
```

plot the long blue line, which will connect all the points, and then plot the prediction on top.